# Where are shell functions stored on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

At first I was looking for the reason that `which` doesn't output anything after giving it certain programs as an argument, e.g. `cd`.

From what I've found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/707906/why-whereis-and-which-dont-show-me-location-of-command), the reason probably is that `cd` on my machine is a function, which is confirmed by running `type cd`.

**TLDR:** But as normal programs that `which` can locate thanks to `$PATH` variable are placed in one of those `$PATH` folders, where are functions or scripts like `cd` stored?

```
user@linuxmchine:~$ type cd
cd is a function
cd () 
{ 
    __zsh_like_cd cd "$@"
}
```

Comment: I get `cd is a shell builtin`. Take a look at the man page for your shell (zsh?)

Comment: Check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then The problem is that which is a legacy command that should not be used - especially because of things like this question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### User defined functions

Typically bash functions are permanently stored in a `bash` start-up script.

- System-wide start-up scripts: `/etc/profile` for login shells, and `/etc/bashrc` for interactive shells.
- User define start-up scripts: `~/.bash_profile` for login shells, and `~/.bashrc` for interactive shells.
- More information on interactive/login shells can be found in the bash `man` page in the INVOCATION section.

User defined shell functions are loaded dynamically in a hash (or lookup table) when bash starts.  From the bash source file `variable.c` the definition for the table is:

```
/* The list of shell functions that the user has created, or that came from
   the environment. */
HASH_TABLE *shell_functions = (HASH_TABLE *)NULL;
```

User defined functions can be listed with the bash `declare` command, other shells still use `typeset`. In bash `declare` has superceded the `typeset` command.

```
declare -f
```

The functions exist in memory for the lifetime of the bash shell.

### Shell defined (builtin) functions

These are common functions such as `echo`, `printf`, `cd` and `:`.  They are compiled into a library which is linked into the `bash` executable. Building the definitions into the executable saves time compared to loading an external definition. Definitions for these functions (held in `.def` source files which are parsed into C source) are held in the `builtins` directory of bash source.

A useful aside: for information on a shell builtin command use `help <command>`.
e.g.

```
help                # list all builtins
help declare        # info and options for declare
help -m declare     # gives man style information for declare
```

Comment: Thank you for that excerpt answer. This is exactly what I've been looking for. Do you think there's a tool to follow bash functions creating process or something like `typeset` that would show what file/script caused the creation/change of a function?

Comment: I don't know of any such tool - it would be a useful option to the `declare` or `typeset` command to display the source file of a function definition. I think it's a software engineering issue. Recently found a shell function defined in a `.alias` file - not what I was expecting!

Answer (score 8):

Shell *functions* are stored in the memory of the shell
(or, perhaps, in undocumented temporary files). 
They don't exist in any usable way until the shell starts
(e.g., when you login to a CLI, or start a shell window such as `xterm`)
and they are defined (e.g., by reading `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or something similar)
and they cease to exist when the shell terminates.

Comment: The ephemeral nature of something you type at the prompt is important.  My vote goes to this answer.  If you type `cd () { pwd; builtin cd "$@"; }` at the prompt then the only place that is stored is in the memory of your currently running shell. (My example is Bash but the same principle applies to any shell.)

Answer (score 6):

`cd` and other common commands like `echo`, `type` & `alias` are so called [builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) .

Builtin commands are contained within the shell itself and different shells may have different built in commands.

Comment: I don't know if it might be worth emphasizing that the executable code for builtin commands like `cd` is contained within the shell program itself, e.g. within the file `/bin/bash` if that is your shell. (I do think your wording here is clear, but I've seen people get confused by all sorts of things.)

Answer (score 2):

The Super User question [Finding the definition of a bash function](https://superuser.com/q/858261/354511)
is closely related to this one. 
User [HairOfTheDog](https://superuser.com/users/59050/hairofthedog) provided [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/229038/354511) (paraphrased):

> The following commands will report the location (filename and line number)
>   of a function’s definition.  Assuming a function named `foo`,
>
> > ```
> > # Turn on extended shell debugging
> > shopt -s extdebug
> >
> > # Display the function’s name, line number and fully qualified source file
> > declare -F foo
> >
> > # Turn off extended shell debugging
> > shopt -u extdebug
> > ```
>
> For example, the output of these commands might be:
>
> > ```
> > foo 32 /source/private/main/developer/cue.pub.sh
> > ```

The above might work only in `bash`, and not in POSIX shells in general.

<sup>Thanks to [Blue Raspberry](https://superuser.com/users/498145/blue-raspberry) for finding this!</sup>